# How to Implement Pagination With Filter in AWS Dynamodb

Tags: java, aws-lambda

QueryResultPage quickLinksQueryResult=mapper.queryPage(Links.class,queryExpression,LinksDynamoDBMapperConfig.get(tableNameLinks));
queryExpression.withExclusiveStartKey(linksQueryResult.getLastEvaluatedKey());

Getting Empty results while filter is applied.What might be error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Both Filter and Pagination cannot be done at same time on the Dynamodb Table. You can execute one or the other, but not both.